# Convert a statement to ES5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I need helps with convert the statement below to ES5 syntax. What will it be in ES5?

```
const { a, b, c = “foo” } = this.props;
```

Comment: `var a = this.props.a, b = this.props.b`

Comment: @rajesh const in ES5...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to use an explicit check if property `c` exists in the given object or not. If not given, then use the default value.

```
var a = this.props.a,
    b = this.props.b,
    c = this.props.c === undefined ? 'foo' : this.props.c;
```

The otherwise used pattern

```
c = this.props.c || 'foo';
```

does not work for given falsy value like zero.

> Why do you need a check with `undefined` (kudos to loganfsmyth for mention this problem in comments)?
>
> Because `undefined` is the value for the check for [default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Default_parameters) in a function in ES6.
>
> ```js
> const f = (c = 'foo') => console.log(c);
>
> f();          // 'foo'
> f(undefined); // 'foo'
> f(0)          // 0
> ```

Comment: Doesn't that need to be `'c' in this.props`?

Comment: @CodingIntrigue, i don't understand the question.

Comment: Doesn't the left-hand side of `in` need to be a string? `c in this.props` would yield an error rather than the expected `true`/`false`.

Comment: Maybe worth noting that using `in` like this isn't quite the same behavior as the ES6 code. The property can exist but be `undefined` and it would still get the default in ES6.

Answer (score 3):

```
 var
   a=this.props.a,
   b=this.props.b,
   c=this.props.c||"foo";
```

Object destructuring trys to find properties with the same name in the object, so

```
 {prop}=obj
```

equals:

```
 prop=obj.prop;
```

The default parameter can be easily achieved with an Or operator:

```
 prop=obj.prop || default;
```

or if you want to count *falsys* as a prop, itll be:

```
 prop=("prop" in obj)?obj["prop"]:default;
```

Comment: @rajesh what should i explain? As the OP knows what object destructuring does, i think its self explaining

Comment: @Jonasw you are not answering for OP. You are answering it for readers. So an explanation is must.

Comment: The explanation is correct but the answer is wrong. you example would set every falsy value of `this.props.c` (like "" or just 0) to the default. This behaviour might not be intended.

Comment: @jonasw that is not quite true. In the case that you want to accept all falsy values BUT `undefinded`. Just wanted to point that out ;)

Comment: `prop=("prop" in obj)?obj["prop"]:default;` isn't quite right. If the `prop` exists but has the value `undefined`, it should also use `default`, but that will read the property.

Comment: I think it relatively common. For a case like this with React especially, you can easily imagine someone doing `<ThingComponent c={someVar} />`. If `someVar` ends up being `undefined`, your snippet would then return `undefined` instead of the `"foo"` default, because the property exists but has an `undefined` value.

Comment: @loganfsmyth ok that might be true

Answer (score 0):

I believe it would be :

```
var a = this.props.a,
    b = this.props.b,
    c = this.props.c || "foo"
```

At least I hope, otherwise it'll be raining downvotes

Comment: There, silently downvoted (as usual), while someone else posted exactly se same answer at the same time and didn't get downvoted... meh

Comment: crazy world... :/

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this would be:

```
var a = this.props.a,
b = this.props.b,
c = this.props.c===undefined?"foo":this.props.c
```

But the better way would be to just use the `this.props` object instead of storing it in local variables.

Comment: `c = this.props.c===undefined?"foo":this.props.c` can be rewritten simply `c = this.props.c || "foo"` (didn't downvote)

Comment: That is not correct! it will transform ALL falsy values (like 0 and "") to the default since `""||"foo" == "foo"`. This behavior might not be intended.